# Redirect From Mozilla Firefox to Google Chrome on Button Click with ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Is there any way to click a button on Mozilla Firefox which launches Google Chrome Application? I'm using React js and this has to be from the frontend side.

Comment: No. Your web page doesn't get to tell the operating system to start a specific application (for super obvious security reasons). The best you can do is have a URL with a protocol that gets passed to the OS for further delegation, and then you have zero control over which actual application will end up getting used, if it's allowed through at all. Also, I struggle to understand why you would ever need this: a browser is a browser, your web page will work in both: can you explain (in your post) why you would even need this?

Comment: I am an employee in this company and the client made a request to redirect users if they come from other browsers apart from Chrome there will be a popup which asks if the want to open the page on Google Chrome.

Comment: That sounds like a client who doesn't understand how web pages work, and your boss should explain to them that they'd be paying money for their employees to waste time on something that doesn't matter. At best you can show people a button going "this site works best in Chrome" (which would be a flat-out lie) and the followup text "click here to visit the Chrome download page" pointing to Google's download page for Chrome.

Comment: Yeah it's true i am a frontend guy and i was killing my head around this idea and i also thought that's impossible to do on the frontend side. Though with Node i could have done this in very simply steps in frontend is impossible , as you said best i can do is send them to the Chrom Download page but still nothing to win there. Thank you for your reply.